# What is the limit of the solution of the differential equation $y'=y(y-1)$ with initial condition $y(0)=2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I am having a bit of trouble understanding this differential equation. Specifically I think I am interpreting the graph wrong. The question asks for $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}y(t) $ given that y'=y(y-1) with initial condition y(0)=2.

Solving this DE, I get that y(t) = $\frac{1}{1-0.5e^t }$ , which approaches 0. Originally, I tried to solve the problem graphically. It looked liked this online graph http://www.mathscoop.com/image-gallery/slope-fields/y(y-1)5-55-5ffffff3300661-1120400190.png.

My understanding is that this is a t-y plane, so doesn't y(t) go to infinity as t increases, given the initial condition?

Comment: if you look at your solution carefully you will see that it goes to infinity in a finite time ( as $t \to \log 2$. )

Comment: Look at the behavior past the vertical asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is $y=\frac{1}{1+c\:e^x}$

The particular solution, starting from $y(0)=2$ is obtained for $c=-0.5$ as you found it :
$$y=\frac{1}{1-0.5\:e^x}$$
This corresponds to the red curve drawn on the graph below. The values of $c$ are marked on the curves.

The difficulty for understanding your own graph comes from the inaccuracy of the graph. First, they are not enough points to suggest the continuous lines. Second, the values of $c$ are not marked on each small segment. So it is impossible to clearly see what are the segments corresponding to the case $c=-0.5$ that we are looking for.

The behaviour is, starting from $(x=0 , y=2)$ and $x$ increassing : $y$ increasses ant tends to infinity when $x$ tends to $\ln(2)$.

If we consider a starting point with $x>\ln(2)$, then $y$ is negative and increasses. Finally $y$ tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to infinity.

[image]

Comment: May I ask what tool you used when plotting this?

Comment: http://patrice-rabiller.fr/SineQuaNon/menusqn.htm